# Google API Access for Android Apps duplicate app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api-console

In regard to Keys for Android apps, if my app name is com.example.awesomeapp and I register that in Google API Console for Google Maps v2, can someone else register the same app with a different key?

If not, how can I tell if someone else has that registered?

Comment: change your package name , after that register again.

Comment: Is there some error that would tell me that someone already has it registered? I can also see activity in Traffic Reports.

Comment: yes ,App is already register with same package.